# Device list says Chromecast device is in "Casting Backdrop" on HTC Desire 620G

Tags: google-cast

I just bought a new HTC Desire 620G phone and tried to run Googlecast sender app.
When it shows the device list, it said Chromecast device is "Casting Backdrop". I tried to cast to Chromecast but the device is still showing background image.

The same sender app can work on another Asus pad and HTC butter fly. 
I dunno why...  any recommendation??

Comment: BTW, I saw it said "Google Play Service is out of date" in logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh... the problem got fixed after I update my google play service,